# screen goes blank when loading ubuntu 12.04 LTS for the 1st time

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS along Win 7(Win 7 in C:\ and ubuntu in D:). After I select ubuntu from Win 7 boot loader, a screen which contains some lines that goes off within a second to the next screen where a cursor blinks. All I can notice from this flashing screen is "NTFS" and after this the screen just goes black.

Note: Before installing ubuntu, I partitioned my C:\ into D:\ with NTFS file system and I'm using alienware 14

Answer (score 0):

1. Some nVidia graphics solutions do not work out of box with Ubuntu.
   [b]Workaround:[/b] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia
2. The greeter is malfunctioning.
   When using lightdm, sometimes I have to restart because there's nothing on screen but it clearly booted.
   [b]Workaround:[/b] Restart until it works.
3. Another monitor is plugged in.
   Do you have a TV, or did you have another monitor plugged in? Unless I explicitly go to Settings, and disable other monitors, sometimes I get a black screen at start up.

[b]Workaround:[/b] Unplug the other monitor(s) and restart. If there's a display toggle try that.

Comment: Thanks! got this problem sorted out! I just installed ubuntu directly from iso instead of using wubi.